# How to list all the snapshots created from a single volume ID EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, snapshot

In the past few months our snapshots backup volume increases and hence our monthly bill in amazon EC2. Now I wanted to delete some of our old EC2 snapshots. So here is the question:

**How to find all the snapshots created from a single Volume ID using EC2 command line tool?**

I tried `ec2-describe-snapshots` but this list all the snapshots. We have lots of snapshots and it is very difficult for me to note them down one by one.

Answer (score 8):

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters "Name=volume-id, Values=vol-1234,vol-5678"
```

to get the values of only the snapshot-ids and the corresponding volumes:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters "Name=volume-id, Values=vol-1234,vol-5678" --query 'Snapshots[*].{SnapshotId:SnapshotId,VolumeId:VolumeId}' --output table
```

Refer : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-snapshots.html

Answer (score 2):

Do `ec2-describe-snapshots --filter "volume-id=vol-12345"`.

Well [documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeSnapshots.html).